# Using write syscall to print integers

Tags: c

I would like to have the equivalent of

```
void print3( char a, uint8_t b, int8_t c )
{
    printf("%c %" PRIu8 " %" PRIi8 "\n", a, b, c);
}
```

using the `write` syscall. The problem is, I don't know how to print an integer using  `write`. Only commands from ANSI C are allowed and using `sprintf` to format strings is forbidden.

Example syntax to use write:

```
const char msg[] = "Hello World!";
write(STDOUT_FILENO, msg, sizeof(msg)-1);
```

Edit: I am not allowed to use `sprintf` neither `itoa`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each digit of the number to be printed is represented as a character.

There are two pieces to the solution:

- calculate the digits of the number in the chosen base, 10 I assume in this case
- convert the digit to a character and write it

For the step of calculating the digits, you will use the `/` and `%` operators; this will give the digits in "reverse" order, so you'll need to squirrel them away before writing them.

For converting the digits to characters, consider two approaches: simple arithmetic (using the ASCII character values), or an array lookup.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the number `155`, if you divide by `100` then there's `1` hundred and the remainder is `55`, divide by `10` you get `5` 10s and the remainder is `5`, divide that by `1` you get `5`. now concatenate those numbers 1-5-5 you get the final number.This should get you started.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to do the conversion yourself. The code below converts to ASCIIZ (C string), not simple ASCII, but it's useable:

```
int ltoa(long x, char *str, size_t str_size)
{
    long y = 1;
    size_t i, s;
    for (s = 0; y < x; s++)
        y *= 10;
    if (str_size < s+1)
        return s+1;
    str[s--] = 0x0;
    while(s)
    {
            str[s--] = '0' + (x % 10);
            x /= 10;
    }
    str[0] = '0' + x;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you know that `9(in ascii) == '0' + 9` :

```
char a =0;
a = '0';
printf("%c",a); //will print 0
a = '0' + 8; 
printf("%c",a);//will print 8
```

[image]

**EDIT:**

```
int a = 1234;
```

now to convert it to `char* b`:
algorithm:

```
for each digit in a:
   b.append(digit+'0')
```

## you have to understand that `char` is a container of `8 bits == byte` and can be a number, a letter in ASCII or whatever you want to represent within 8 bits